# Statistically testing difference between two sets of data in multiple situations

Tags: hypothesis-testing

We have been conducting a small study recently that, basically, looks at actual behaviour and self-estimated behaviour in a number of situations and is trying to figure out whether they are similar or not. The data we have now is then nine different situations, with two sets of data for each (actual vs self-estimated).

Obviously we're familiar with the most common ways to analyse data statistically, but we're running into some problems here. It's pretty easy to just do nine t-tests (so for every situation, is there a significant difference between actual and self-estimated), but we feel like there should be a better way to do it (and if there's not, how would you reasonably report that in an article?). ANOVA is the first thought when there are more than two groups, but can you do that when they all come in pairs that are only interesting to be compared to each other? How would you do that?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The way you have described your research question it seems you are more interested in the discrepancy between actual behaviour and self-estimated behaviour rather than mean group differences. Since you have decided to do t-tests I assume that data are normally distributed. Therefore, a Pearson's correlation adjusted for the 9 different situations, or a linear regression using the different situations as covariates might serve your purpose well.

In any case, you could run a series of 9 t-tests but make sure you adjust the p value for the number of comparisons (for example by dividing 0.05 by the number of tests, i.e. 0.05/9= 0.006).

Finally, a repeated measures MANCOVA might suit you too if you are interested in the actual mean differences across the 9 situations.

Answer (score 1):

If your initial data is as follows:

```
> mydf
  situation subjectID self actual
1         1         1    5      5
2         1         2    6      6
3         1         3    3      8
4         2         1    5      9
5         2         2    6      4
6         2         3    8      5
>
```

You can convert it to:

```
> mm
   situation subjectID variable value
1          1         1     self     5
2          1         2     self     6
3          1         3     self     3
4          2         1     self     5
5          2         2     self     6
6          2         3     self     8
7          1         1   actual     5
8          1         2   actual     6
9          1         3   actual     8
10         2         1   actual     9
11         2         2   actual     4
12         2         3   actual     5
>
```

And apply anova with error correction:

```
> summary(aov(value~variable+situation+ Error(subjectID/(situation+variable)), data=mm))

Error: subjectID
          Df                               Sum Sq                              Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals  1 0.0000000000000000000000000000003326 0.0000000000000000000000000000003326               

Error: subjectID:situation
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
situation  1 0.6429  0.6429

Error: subjectID:variable
         Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
variable  1 0.6429  0.6429

Error: Within
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
variable   1   1.19    1.19   0.238  0.643
situation  1   1.19    1.19   0.238  0.643
Residuals  6  30.00    5.00
```

This should be the result for self vs actual and for situations, after correcting for subject difference.